# while fetching count of two column in same table not showing proper count of second column

Tags: sql-server

my stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Driverperformance] 
 @Ecode nvarchar(50),  
 @startdate datetime,
 @enddate datetime  as
begin  
    SELECT e.Ecode,CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date , 
           e.Ename, 
           count(q.Ecode) CntEcode ,
           count(q.DelEcode) CntDelEcode
    FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
     inner JOIN Transaction_tbl q  
      ON e.Ecode = q.Ecode 
    where q.Ecode=@Ecode
     and dtime between '' + @startdate +'' and ''+@enddate+'' 
    group by e.Ecode, e.Ename, CAST(q.dtime AS date) 
    ORDER BY CAST(q.dtime AS date)--e.Ecode DESC
end
```

i passed my parameter like this:
`@Ecode = 'E003' @startdate = '2013-09-03', @enddate = '2013-09-03'`

[image]

am getting out put like this: but cntDelEcode is getting wrong.(i am not getting count of DelEcode proper) so what i have to changed in stored procedure)

for checking count of CntEcode i worte query like this:

```
select * from Transaction_tbl where dtime >='2013-09-03 00:00:00.000' and dtime <='2013-09-03 23:59:59.000' and Ecode='E003'
```

. now i am getting 27 rows.so i understood my cntEcode count is corect.
for checking count of CntDelEcode i worte query like this:

```
select * from Transaction_tbl where dtime >='2013-09-03 00:00:00.000' and dtime <='2013-09-03 23:59:59.000' and DelEcode='E003'
```

now i am getting 35 rows..but while executing my stored procedure i am getting only 23 rows insetd of getting 35 rows..where my stored procedure gone wrong? please help me to find out

Answer (score 0):

In the query where you get 35 rows, you are counting the rows where `DelECode='E0003'`

Which is **a different query** to the above query. No wonder the results are different.

You could change your query to

```
SELECT e.Ecode,CAST(q.dtime AS DATE) as Date , 
       e.Ename, 
       count(q.Ecode) CntEcode ,
       (select count(*) from Transaction_tbl 
               where q.Ecode=@Ecode
               and dtime between @startdate and @enddate) CntDelEcode
FROM EmployeeMaster_tbl e 
     ...
```

Comment: in my stored procedure i want to get count of  CntDelEcode is 35..so how i can re-write

Comment: Sir,,while i am testing if i given different date  am not getting proper answer:i given query like this:(select count(*) from Transaction_tbl where dtime >= '' + @date1 +'' and dtime <= ''+@date2+'' and DelEcode=@Ecode group by DelEcode)